# Providing help documentation in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, provider, documents

I have written up troubleshooting documents for my project and would like them included in my program. I remember in VB6 there was a very easy way to do this with a control, where it already has the help document tree set up on the left and you just set it to point to certain files.

Does something like this exist for .NET? I am aware of the `HelpProvider` control but as far as I know  this just puts in tooltips and opens documents on a button press?

Thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge no such interface exists in Visual Studio, at least in the express editions that I have installed here. As your investigations showed you, the only way to provide help is to add a `HelpProvider` to a form and set its `HelpNamespace` property to your HTM/CHM file. Then on each control you can manually set the `HelpKeyword`, `HelpString` and/or `HelpNavigator` properties. Setting the last option controls how the values of `HelpKeyword` or `HelpString` are passed to the external help file.